# Can't fetch the second table data from or with the first table in Laravel relationship

Tags: laravel, phpmyadmin, wamp

I can't fetch the second table data from or with the first table in the Laravel relationship.

**Error**

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cars.mec_id'
> in 'where clause'  SELECT * FROM `cars` WHERE `cars`.`mec_id` = 1 AND
> `cars`.`mec_id` IS NOT NULL limit 1

**mecs Migration**

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('mecs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**cars Migration**

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('cars', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');              // **also used $table->id();**
        $table->string('name');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('eid');
        $table->foreign('eid')->references('id')->on('mecs');   // **also used foreignId
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**car Model**

```
function display()
{
    return $this->hasOne(car::class);
}
```

**Controller**

```
class relation extends Controller
{
    function show($id){
        return mec::find($id)->display;   // **also used  ->with(display)
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't follow default Laravel [naming conventions](https://webdevetc.com/blog/laravel-naming-conventions/), based on your relation and model name, Laravel is assuming that your `cars` table has `mec_id` column. Looking at the given example above, you're using `eid` column for that relation. So in order to map out your relation to use that column instead, you have to change the `display()` relation to this:

```
function display()
{
    return $this->hasOne(car::class, 'eid');
}
```

You can read more about it here: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Comment: Thanks since i just learning Laravel But after doing the above change it only display the second table record(doesn't Display combine first and second table record).Please help

Comment: I would like to add that the Laravel naming conventions can be very important. Use the name "Car" instead of "car" for your model. It's also strange to have a relationship called "display" that returns a "Car" model. It van be very confusing for other developers. Since you are still learning, learn the correct namings and prevent problems in the future

Comment: @Sam well for that, you would need to include your view file, so we can see how you're displaying the data.

Comment: like this on controller  return mec::find($id)->display;

Comment: @Sam Well you could just use return mec::find($id)->with('display);

That will return mec record, but it will load relation data as well.

Comment: @Sam Laravel is a MVC framework, so typically a controller returns a view (or another response if you use ajax for example) and not a Model.  I would advise you to read the docs or follow a tutorial to understand the basics. If you follow some simple rules, Laravel will do most of the work for you.